# The object has no method split

Tags: jquery

HEllo guys i have a script that run fine in Chrome and FF but seems not working in IE...
Although it has a java script error and i cannot solve it 
the error is

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){var b=this;var d=[];for(var
>   a=b.length;a--;){var
>   c=b[a];if(jQuery.inArray(c,d)===-1)d.unshift(c)}return d} has no
>   method 'split'

Please help

```
    function populate(s1,s2){
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
    s2.innerHTML = "";
    if(s1.value == "bedroom"){
        var optionArray = ["|Room Type","private|Private","shared|Shared","suite|Suite"];
    } else if(s1.value == "house"){
        var optionArray = ["|House Type","beach_house|Beach House","bungalow|Bungalow","cabin|Cabin","chateau|Chateau","house|House","cottage|Cottage","lake_house|Lake House","ski_chalet|Ski Chalet","townhosue|Townhouse","villa|Villa"];
    } else if(s1.value == "apartment"){
        var optionArray = ["|Appartment Type","apartment|Apartment","apartment_hotel|Apartment Hotel","condo|Condo","loft|Loft","luxury_apartment|Luxury Apartment","serviced_aparment|Serviced Apartment"];
    } else if(s1.value == "bnb"){
        var optionArray = ["|B&B Type","room|Room","suite|Suite"];
    } else if(s1.value == "hotel"){
        var optionArray = ["|Hotel Type","boutique_hotel|Boutique Hotel","budget_hotel|Budget Hotel","hotel|Hotel","inn|Inn","resort|Resort"];
    } else if(s1.value == "hostel"){
        var optionArray = ["|Hostel Type","hostel|Hostel"];
    }
    for(var option in optionArray){
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair[0];
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
        s2.options.add(newOption);
    }
}
```

Comment: add a console.log before split, one of your `optionArray[option]` is probably undefined

Comment: Before your `for` loop, check if `optionArray` is defined.

Comment: 1) Avoid `for-in` on arrays, at least without special reason; 2) looks like the assumed value `optionArray[option]` is not being found. Try console logging it before running `split` on it.

Comment: you are defining var optionArray in if and some else if, but not in a generic else, so option array can be undefined. What is the value of s1.value when you face the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using some extension that adds properties to the array prototype, so IE operates on additional values that other browsers do not. The direct fix is to [not use `for..in` on your array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea), use a plain `for` instead:

```
for(var i = 0; i < optionArray.length; ++i) {
    // and now use optionArray[i] instead of optionArray[option]
}
```

Another option would be to filter out these properties with

```
for(var option in optionArray){
    if (!optionArray.hasOwnProperty(option)) continue;
    // the rest without modification
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the var `optionArray` inside an if and some else if, but not in a generic else, so in some case `optionArray` can be undefined.

You can move the definition at the top of the if, or define a generic else.

Code:

```
function populate(s1,s2){
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
    s2.innerHTML = "";
    var optionArray=new Array();
    if(s1.value == "bedroom"){
        optionArray = ["|Room Type","private|Private","shared|Shared","suite|Suite"];
    } else if(s1.value == "house"){
        optionArray = ["|House Type","beach_house|Beach House","bungalow|Bungalow","cabin|Cabin","chateau|Chateau","house|House","cottage|Cottage","lake_house|Lake House","ski_chalet|Ski Chalet","townhosue|Townhouse","villa|Villa"];
    } else if(s1.value == "apartment"){
        optionArray = ["|Appartment Type","apartment|Apartment","apartment_hotel|Apartment Hotel","condo|Condo","loft|Loft","luxury_apartment|Luxury Apartment","serviced_aparment|Serviced Apartment"];
    } else if(s1.value == "bnb"){
        optionArray = ["|B&B Type","room|Room","suite|Suite"];
    } else if(s1.value == "hotel"){
        optionArray = ["|Hotel Type","boutique_hotel|Boutique Hotel","budget_hotel|Budget Hotel","hotel|Hotel","inn|Inn","resort|Resort"];
    } else if(s1.value == "hostel"){
        optionArray = ["|Hostel Type","hostel|Hostel"];
    }
    for(var option in optionArray){
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair[0];
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
        s2.options.add(newOption);
    }
}
```